# FreeRTOS priority 1 is special?

Tags: c, scheduled-tasks, stm32, freertos

FreeRTOS priority 1 is special?

In my system,i have 6 priority 0-5. I know the idle pro at 0.

i assign a task at 1,others at 2-5.from the cpu time and IDEL pro info ,i could know the cpu have enough time to do all tasks.

I found a problem that the task at 1 could not work at the right time,the frequence is 10Hz,but i found sometimes it not work. maybe 8 or lower than 10,even lower than 1Hz.

when i set the task at 2,it's ok,work at 10Hz.

The code struct like this:

```
void SYS_MONITOR::run(){
    int ret = 0;

    while(1){
        vTaskDelayUntil(&last_wake_time, SYS_MONITOR_RUN_INTERVAL_MS/portTICK_RATE_MS);
dosomething....
}
```

```
ID  State   Prio    Mark    CPU(%)      Name

1   S   1   261 0.0000000   God
2   R   0   109 69.6136779  IDLE
3   S   5   470 3.9053585   Tmr Svc
...
...
44  B   2   179 0.0242588   SYS_MONITOR_run
Heap   : Total 491520   , Used 193696   , Remain 297824
DmaHeap: Total 16384    , Used 2048 , Remain 14336
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no enough information to answer this.
You have quite large setup , by looking at the number of tasks you have.

One thing :

```
1   S   1   261 0.0000000   God
 .....
4   B   2   179 0.0242588   SYS_MONITOR_run
5   R   1   303 0.0142761   SYS_CLI_SERV_run
```

You have at least 2 Tasks with priority 1 there. If your SYS_MONITOR_run was 1 also and started working "better" after you bumped it's priority to 2 (higher) that is not surprising.

It depends on your scheduler configuration how the equal priority tasks get chance to run, e.g.: do you have time slicing round-robin or FIFO on equal priority tasks? That's one. ...

Two, you have complex setup (44 Tasks!) and too little info to really answer your question.

Comment: Thank you for it.  the problem task is SYS_MONITOR_run, the priority 1 God and SYS_CLI_SERV_run usually not work when SYS_MONITOR_run works.so you could think just one task in priority 1.

Comment: 44 Task is too much for FreeRTOS?? But from the idle cpu use could see it have the  time to do more?

Comment: I didn't say 'too much for FreeRTOS'; what I tried to point out is that, I felt, it's difficult to answer your question with information you gave, because you have a large setup  (44 tasks is not a small RTOS based system)